# Как установить debian 8 jessie на машину с nvme ssd

Tags: debian, grub, ssd, nvme

Хочу установить ос debian 8 jessie на ноутбук с ssd, в процессе установки получаю ошибку о том что загрузчик grub не установлен как это можно исправить? Любые советы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: debian 12 bookworm

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin любые советы как установить 8ку

Comment: если нужна 8-ка, то ставим на жесткий диск.

Comment: @nexoma, я мог подумать что установка jessie не возможна на ssd

Comment: ok. на англоязычном решение есть. ищите.